# Where default value populated in this script?

Tags: javascript, default-value

Trying to find out where default value for field with id **startDate** is populated.
Its "24/04/2008" in rendered window on bottom right, however cannot see where it was set in code.

```
// this methid is called each time the selected period of the chart is changed
function handleZoom(event) {
    var startDate = event.startDate;
    var endDate = event.endDate;
    document.getElementById("startDate").value = AmCharts.formatDate(startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    document.getElementById("endDate").value = AmCharts.formatDate(endDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
// as we also want to change graph type depending on the selected period, we call this method
changeGraphType(event);
}
// this method is called when user changes dates in the input field
function changeZoomDates() {
    var startDateString = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
    var endDateString = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    var startDate = stringToDate(startDateString);
    var endDate = stringToDate(endDateString);
    chart.zoomToDates(startDate, endDate);
}

<input onChange="changeZoomDates()" style="width:100px; text-align:center" type="text" id="startDate">
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nos0q1dL/

Comment: The default date is not set in this code . . . Do you have any other relevant code?

Comment: Try a browser you dont use often. Could it be auto-populating a quite popular field name (Start date) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not too much documentation, but see this part:

```
// this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
function zoomChart() {
    // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 7, chartData.length - 1);
 }
```

Read it: zoom to last 7 days when first showing the chart, you can confirm by changing 7 to 10 for example.

To show everything, you would do:

```
    chart.zoomToIndexes( 0, chartData.length - 1);
```

The 1st parameter is the index of the starting position and the 2nd is the index of the ending position.

Answer (score 0):

If by "default value" you're referring to "initial value", then it must be:

```
document.getElementById("startDate").value = AmCharts.formatDate(startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Replace that line with:

```
document.getElementById("startDate").value = "01/01/2007";
```

And you will see.